# How does one correctly add custom SQL DML in migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I had a situation today where I wanted to add a partial postgres index to a table in a migration. Naturally this kind of stuff is not possible yet in rails using `add_index` (it is [coming some time](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d70e0236df61d69c9299fe63df94da35c87ee2d8))

So, I am forced to use `execute` statements in my migration.

Now, `schema.rb` has this comment at the top:

```
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
```

Unfortunately this `execute` statement is not tracked in `schema.rb` the effect of this is making `schema.rb` pretty much useless if I have any custom DML.

Is there any way I can force an `execute` statement containing DML to find itself into `schema.rb` ?

Comment: To add to this question, is there a way to do this using rake in such a way that whenever rake creates a database, it runs a script containing all the custom SQL DML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to achieve what you want with schema.rb,  what you want to do is switch to using the database's native schema dumping / retrieval code.

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Now instead of a schema.rb file, you'll get a structure.sql file.  This should transparently work with all rails' built in tasks and as it's using the native dumper format, it'll support whatever crazy stuff you want it to.